# apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken in docusign doesn't work

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core-mvc, docusignapi

I'm using DocuSign C# SDK to create a JWT token to impersonate as a user using an Integrator key but it throws an error saying:

`Error while requesting server, received a non-successful HTTP code`

I'm simply calling the `UpdateToken()` method which is like this:

```
 private static void UpdateToken()
        {
            var apiClient = new ApiClient();

            OAuth.OAuthToken authToken = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(ClientID, ImpersonatedUserGuid, AuthServer, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PrivateKey), TokenExpiryInHours, new List<string> { "signature", "impersonation" });

            AccessToken = authToken.access_token;

            TokenExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(authToken.expires_in.Value);
        }
```

values for all the parameters passed in `RequestJWTUserToken`are:

```
 "DocuSign": {       
    "ClientID": "aff67220-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-426b6575c3bd",
    "ImpersonatedUserGuid": "f9a0f822-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-7a576f06df81",
    "AuthServer": "https://account-d.docusign.com",
    "TokenReplacementTimeInSeconds": "600",
    "TokenExpiryInHours": "1",
    "PrivateKey": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\XXXXXXX\r\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
  }
```

I have taken the consent from the user by using this endpoint:

https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?
response_type=token&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=aff67220-3ca7-4de7-8556-426b6575c3bd
&redirect_uri=https://www.vava.cars/tr/admin

and the user has successfully allowed this clientId/integrator key to have the permissions.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the `Audience` value (`AuthServer` in your code), you need to drop the `https://` prefix and set that to `account-d.docusign.com`

Comment: Hey, That worked but I am not happy with this haha. Thanks Drew :)