# DocuSign REST API .Net framework SDK - How to correctly generate token (error: issuer_not_found)

Tags: .net, rest, token, docusignapi

i trying generate token for implicit grant.

Example calling code:

```
public static string GetAccessToken()
        {
            string accessToken = "";

            try
            {
                ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");

                string integrationKey = "75fe59b8-b2f6-499d-89bb-da9d0f1ee4ea";
                string userId = "7c36c435-d8eb-4b71-b46c-a4d4b20b06e1";// Impersonated User GUID

                string sPrivatekey = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\Temp\DocuTest2\key.pem");

                byte[] privatekey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sPrivatekey);

                List<string> scopes = new List<string>() { OAuth.Scope_SIGNATURE }; // OAuth.Scope_IMPERSONATION

                var token = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(integrationKey, userId, OAuth.Demo_OAuth_BasePath, privatekey, 1000, scopes);

                return accessToken;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return accessToken;
            }
        }
```

with errror:
"Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code Completed with response Body: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"issuer_not_found"}"

How it correctly call this function? What is wrong?

Thank's a lot!

Update:Hi i need generate token from .net framework sdk without web - implicit grant. For my library project (DLL) which next is calling from Delphi.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken in docusign doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989496/apiclient-requestjwtusertoken-in-docusign-doesnt-work)

Comment: Thanks but don't working ...

Comment: Are you using implicit grant or jwt grant? You question is inconsistent. Ask a new question if you're using implicit grant.  For a delphi app you'd probably use implicit grant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for our scenario is call this..

public static void CallAuthorizationURLforConsent(string clientId, string basePath, string redirectUrl)
{
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);

```
            List<string> scopes = new List<string>() { OAuth.Scope_SIGNATURE, OAuth.Scope_IMPERSONATION, OAuth.Scope_EXTENDED };

            Uri uri = apiClient.GetAuthorizationUri(clientId, scopes, redirectUrl, OAuth.CODE, null);

            //Open browser and accept consent
            Process.Start(uri.ToString());

            return;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need "impersonation" scope as well for JWT.

```
List<string> scopes = new List<string>() { OAuth.Scope_SIGNATURE }; // OAuth.Scope_IMPERSONATION
```

Not sure why it's commented out but that is not going to work with impersonation.

Comment: Thnaks but don't working. 
Tried a long time ago but I added it there now

Comment: `impersonation` scope is optional since it is implicitly included by the JWT grant flow. It is required for the consent process if the JWT flow will be used.

Comment: would be easier if you used the C# SDK. But not clear if you want to use JWT or Implicit Grant?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is referring to the `Issuer` parameter. That's the `ISS` claim which is the `client_id` (Integration Key). So check that it is correct.

Also check that the `aud` setting is account-d.docusign.com NOT https://account-d.docusign.com

If you're using this app in production, then use account.docusign.com But you must first complete the go-live process.

Your scope is fine. `impersonation` scope is assumed by the JWT grant flow (but it can be optionally included). `impersonation` and `signature` scopes must both be requested during the consent process.

Also, your example is using the JWT grant, not the Implicit grant. The Implicit grant flow is an entirely different kettle of fish and is not implemented by the SDK. Instead, your app implements it.

Comment: Hi, thanks.
How to set JWT grant in Authentitacition section in Apps and Keys.
There is only Implicit grant or Authorization Code Grant (but this is not contain RSA keypairs  - private key)

Comment: Before call GetAccessToken() i must call anything else?
What I must set to redirect uri? We can try this ...
https://localhost:8000/ds/callback
http://localhost:8080/authorization-code/callback
http://localhost:8080/ds/callback
https://localhost:44333/ds/callback
https://localhost:5000/ds/callback
...

Comment: In comment was remove h_t_t_p_s prefix .. i don't know why..

Comment: Hi i need generate token from .net framework sdk without web - implicit grant. For my library project (DLL) which next  is calling from Delphi.