# Getting Consent For A Console Application

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am trying to create a console program that gets all of the Envelope EmailSubject's from the last day.

I am having trouble with consent and I keep getting the error:

> DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: 'Error while requesting server,
> received a non successful HTTP code Completed with response Body:
> {"error":"consent_required"}'

I get this message after running the following code:

```
var apiClient = new ApiClient();
        string ik = _configuration.IntegrationKey;
        string userId = _configuration.UserId;
        string authServer = _configuration.AuthServer;
        string rsaKey = DSHelper.ReadFileContent(DSHelper.PrepareFullPrivateKeyFilePath(_configuration.PrivateKeyFile));
        OAuth.OAuthToken authToken = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(ik,
                        userId,
                        authServer,
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rsaKey),
                        1);
```

I understand that I need to "Grant consent to an internal application" using the DocuSign Admin portal steps found here: [How to obtain admin consent for internal applications/](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-admin-consent-internal/)

However, even after adding my application to the connected app list, I am still getting the "{"error":"consent_required"}" error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: how many users are going to use this application? the userId seems to come from configuration? is it fixed? meaning, it will always be the same?

Comment: similar question, might help to look at it  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989496/apiclient-requestjwtusertoken-in-docusign-doesnt-work

Comment: @InbarGazit  I'm trying to have no users. The UserId is actually the impersonated userId in the JSON config. I'm trying to build a program that will run once per night as an integration with some billing software. I would like to call the API without any user login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consent is needed only once, ever, per a specific integration and a user.
Since you have only one user, you just need to do this once and you're good.

Open a browser to this URL after you add https://www.docusign.com as a valid redirect in the [Apps and Keys page](https://admindemo.docusign.com/authenticate?goTo=apiIntegratorKey) for your IK:

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=<YOUR_IK>&redirect_uri=https://www.docusign.com
```

(update your IK)